# Visual Studio 2012 suddenly crashes when moving controls on form in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, crash, .net-4.5

When i move around certain elements (EDIT: narrowed it down to size/location changes to  controls that have SuspendLayout,ResumeLayout and PerformLayout called on them and only if the cahnges are made using the mouse - direct editing works as it should) on my MainForm in the designer, VS crashes and tells me it has stopped working. When i debug using a second instance, the debugger gives me an unhandled NullReferenceException in devenv.exe. The problem suddenly appeared out of nowhere and seems to be pretty resistant - i repaired VS, reinstalled the .Net framework (4.5 SDK), restarted the machine, ran VS as admin etc. I'm on Windows 8 latest release and i use Visual Studio 2012 Premium.

The only third party plugin i use is git-ext.

Does anyone have experience with bugs like that one? Until today i believed stuff like this is more subject of the Java/Eclipse world...Thanks in advance for any hints, i'm kind of getting desperate here :))I will of course provide any additional information needed! Cheers

Edit

Here is the exception i get when debugging with a second instance of VS:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled


HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Design
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.AdornerWindow.MouseHook.MouseHookProc(Int32 nCode, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Following Kyle's instructions (thanks a lot for the input!!), i tried the following so far:

1. Reboot into safemode - no change
2. Create new user account - no change
3. Remove all add ins and run in safemode - no change
4. Reset settings - no change
5. create a new project (simple form with some controls) - everything works, no crash, so it really seems the problem is related to the project
6. Repair VS - no change

EDIT 2

It also crashes when i add a new GroupBox container as soon as i drag it, change its size or delete it

EDIT 3

Following the instructions of Avi i was able to resolve the issue - it seems to be caused by a bug in VS2012, i had a GroupBox control hidden behind some other controls, as soon as i removed it, the error was gone.

Comment: Can you specify which elements you are moving? Is it a specific one? is it a custom user control? A user control that belongs to the .NET framework / third party?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!I played around a little more with it and it seems i can narrow it down to Windows.Forms.GroupBox controls.

Comment: Does the group box contain any other controls?

Comment: Yeah, but if i add a new empty GroupBox it behaves exactly the same way. I now figured out that it only crashes when i use the mouse to modify size/location. When edit the properties directly, it works like a charm.

Comment: Is there a method registered to the `resized` event?

Comment: no, there is not, however on further investigation on some other controls i found, that also some TabPage controls etc. cause the crash when moved or resized. The thing that all these controls have in common, is that the SuspendLayout(), ResumeLayout(false) and PerformLayout() are called on them....

Comment: if you put them in a try-catch clause does it still happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35498/discussion-between-user871784-and-avi-turner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the summary of comments / [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35498/discussion-between-user871784-and-avi-turner) regarding this question:

In order to track down the issue I would try to:

1. Check which elements are being moved.
2. Do they have any events registered to their moved / resized events?
3. If so, is the Exception occurring in the event handler?
4. If not, Is the error occurring in the constructor of the control / form?

If you have located the source of the exception, try wrapping it with a try-catch clause.
bear in mind that At design time, the designer simulates a call to a constructor in order to "build" your designer.
so, wrapping the call to `InitializeComponent` with a try-catch clause, should get exceptions in `designers` file.

Answer (score 2):

please try the following workarounds:

1. If we reboot the operating system to safe mode, do we have the problem? This can help to isolate whether any other applications are interfering with Visual Studio. Note that some features (like IIS) are not available under safe mode. Please check whether this can apply or not. In addition to safe mode, you can also try “clean boot”: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353 .
2. If we create a new user account, do we have the problem? This can help to isolate user profile corruption related causes.
3. If we disable Add-ins (e.g. “Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) and run “devenv.exe /safemode”, do we still have the problem? This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins are causing problems.
4. If we use “devenv.exe /resetsettings”, does it solve the problem? It restores Visual Studio default settings.
5. If we create a new project, do we have the problem? Sometimes corrupted project settings can cause problems. These are project specific.
6. If the problem remains, we can use Visual Studio Setup Wizard (via Control Panel) to repair Visual Studio. It can restore the Visual Studio Installation into its original state.

In addition, please refer to the following connect link, see whether you encounter the same issue .

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672192/visual-studio-keeps-crashing-for-a-c-windows-form-application-after-opening-a-source-file